# find complex matrices

Tags: complex-numbers, matrix-equations

Find complex matrices satisfying the following equation

[image]

What I have is solution based on real numbers. How can I come to a solution in complex numbers?

[image]

Comment: Note that all those real solutions are also complex solutions, and the first set of solutions (starting with $b\neq 0$) works just as well for complex $a, b, c, d$ as it does for just real $a, b, c, d$.

Comment: Please enter critical parts of your question as text using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for mathematical expressions instead of pasting pictures of it. Your question is incomprehensible without those images and thus inaccessible to people who depend on screen readers. Moreover, images are neither searchable nor show up in summaries.

Answer (score 2):

If $X^{2} - \operatorname{Id} = 0$,; it means that the minimal polynomial of $X$, denoted with $m_{X}(t)$ divides the polynomial $t^{2}-1 = (t+1)(t-1)$.

Now you just have three cases to deal with, which run out the values founded with WolframAlpha, which are complex indeed, since $\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$.

---

**Edit**: To be more specific, you have all the conjugacy classes of the three case mentioned above. Hence you have the matrix $I$, $-I$ and all the matrix of the form
$$
M
\left[
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & -1
\end{matrix}
\right]
M^{-1}
$$
with $M\in \text{GL}(2,\mathbb C)$.